# How can I take my onClick output and put it on a card?

Tags: css, reactjs, json

If I have a console output from here:

```
const PeriodicTable = () => {
  
  
  return (
    <div layout className="periodic-table">
      {data.elements.map((element) => (
        <button
          className="element"
          key={element.name}
          onClick={()=> {console.log(element)}}
          style={{
            gridRow: element.ypos,
            gridColumn: element.xpos,
            borderColor: colorMap[element.category],
          }}
```

So when I click on an element on the periodic table the console.log(element) is an output of element data from a JSON file. All I want is to take the output and print it out onto a html tag. I've already tried the document.write() method but to no avail.

Comment: This card/html tag is another component somewhere in your dom? I’m assuming you have buttons for every element and then want to show a card for the one element that has been selected? If so, I’d recommend just saving a state containing the selected element in the parent component of both the button list and the card element and passing the setState to the button list, and the element state itself to the card.

Comment: Yes the card is a separate component in my project file. As you can see my buttons are the product of a map function over every element. Can I not just click on an element and print the data on to a card in the same way control.log does in my DOM?

Comment: Technically, you can get a reference to your card component using useRef and set it using ref.current.dangerouslySetInnerHtml, but I personally think using useState and passing setState to your button component is more clear and sustainable for your code. That’s how I’d solve your problem at least. It’s not a lot of code either. About three edited lines in your parent component and then two lines per child component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you can pass that value from button to the state on parent components, and just pass it to Card Component

let's say you have json like this

```
const data = {
  elements: [
    {
      name: "steve",
      ypos: 1,
      xpos: 1,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      name: "james",
      ypos: 2,
      xpos: 2,
      color: "red"
    }
  ]
};
```

and PeriodicTabel will look like this

```
const PeriodicTable = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="periodic-table">
      {data.elements.map((element, id) => (
        <button
          key={id}
          className="element"
          onClick={() => props.handleOnCLick(element)}
          style={{
            width: "100px",
            gridRow: element.ypos,
            gridColumn: element.xpos,
            borderColor: element.color
          }}
        >
          click me
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

then in app component you can make handleOnclick to make it as props on PeridocTable component

```
export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState({});
  const handleOnCLick = (val) => {
    setVal(val);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PeriodicTable handleOnCLick={handleOnCLick} />
      <Card value={val} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

so in app component you can make a state to accept value from the button on PeriodicTable component

```
const [val, setVal] = useState({});
```

and then you can pass it to the card

```
 <Card value={val} />
```

Card component will be look like this

```
const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="card"
      style={{
        width: "200px",
        background: "red",
        height: "250px",
        margin: "0 auto"
      }}
    >
      <h2>title card</h2>
      <p>{props.value.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is final result of the source code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = {
  elements: [
    {
      name: "steve",
      ypos: 1,
      xpos: 1,
      color: "red"
    },
    {
      name: "james",
      ypos: 2,
      xpos: 2,
      color: "red"
    }
  ]
};

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="card"
      style={{
        width: "200px",
        background: "red",
        height: "250px",
        margin: "0 auto"
      }}
    >
      <h2>title card</h2>
      <p>{props.value.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const PeriodicTable = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="periodic-table">
      {data.elements.map((element, id) => (
        <button
          key={id}
          className="element"
          onClick={() => props.handleOnCLick(element)}
          style={{
            width: "100px",
            gridRow: element.ypos,
            gridColumn: element.xpos,
            borderColor: element.color
          }}
        >
          click me
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState({});
  const handleOnCLick = (val) => {
    setVal(val);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PeriodicTable handleOnCLick={handleOnCLick} />
      <Card value={val} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[link to the preview in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-lehmann-kktx21?file=/src/App.js:0-1298)